# JBoss EJB Remote Client version corresponding to server version

Tags: maven, jboss

In the Readme-File of the `jboss-client`, it says:

> Maven users should not use this jar, but should use the following BOM dependencies instead [...]
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
>     <artifactId>jboss-as-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
>     <type>pom</type>
> </dependency>
> ```

In the [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.as/jboss-as-ejb-client-bom), there are several different versions of `jboss-as-ejb-client-bom`. Unfortunately, there is no indication in the readme, which version of this artifact to use.

When using JBoss libraries, I usually declare this dependency in the `pom.xml`'s `dependencyManagement` section in the version corresponding to JBoss server version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
    <artifactId>eap-runtime-artifacts</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.GA</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

In the `eap-runtime-artifacts` BOM, the `jboss-as-ejb-client-bom` is not managed, thus I need to specify a version. As there is also no version `7.0.0.GA` of the client, I am not sure which version to use. So, my questions basically is:

Do I have to use a specific version of jboss-client (artifact `jboss-as-ejb-client-bom`), depending on which version of JBoss server (artifact `eap-runtime-artifacts`) I use? If so, where do I find the corresponding versions of client and server?

Comment: It would help to know exactly what version of JBossAS or JBoss EAP that you have.

Comment: @SteveC JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA. At the moment, but of course this might change.